# What is the value of the test !"".equals(someString)

Tags: java, coding-style

In a project I've been trying to familiarise myself with, I ran across a method that looks like this:

```
public boolean testString(String string){
    return string != null && !"".equals(string);
}
```

What is the value of testing the string for emptiness this way instead of with the variable first? I understand why we see constant-first (Yoda syntax) in C, but is there any reason to do so with method calls in Java?

note: I do understand about NullPointerException, which is not possible in this instance. I'm looking for a value to doing it this way in this case particularly.

Comment: I only ask because it caught my eye. After seeing tests the other way 'round for so long, this looks weird to me.

Comment: Probably just someone's leftover habits from C...

Comment: if you use "".equals(string) it won't throw a npe if string is null whereas if you use string.equals("") it will

Comment: If you use string != null it won't throw NPE either.

Comment: Yes of course, I was just pointing at the specific way of writing it in the "yoda syntax", in this case it doesn't have any specific reason, but in another context it can be used to avoid having a null check before.

Comment: `"".equals(string)` is a terribly inefficient way to test for a zero length string. When there is a test for `!= null` (as in your example) then using `string.length() == 0` or `string.isEmpty()` is a lot more efficient.

Comment: My preference is also to use the isEmpty() method, since this most clearly show what your intent in performing the check is. This is something I ran across in a Java 1.5 code base, however, that has been floating around the company for at least a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two strings it doesn't matter much, but when there is a non-`final` type involved it can be a micro-optimization.

If the left hand side is a non-overridden concrete type, then the dispatch becomes static.

Consider what the JIT has to do for

```
Object o;
String s;

o.equals(s)
```

vs

```
s.equals(o)
```

In the first, the JIT has to find the actual `equals` method used, whereas in the second, it knows that it can only by `String.equals`.

I adopted the habit of doing

```
"constant value" == variableName
```

in other languages, since it means that the code will fail to parse if I mis-type `=` instead of `==`.
And when I learned Java, I kept that order preference.

Comment: I hadn't considered the overhead of locating the method. For testing against constants like this, I can see that the switch in order might provide a clear advantage in methods being called a lot.

Comment: @Zoe, yeah.  It's just a micro-optimization, but when you've done all the macro-optimizations, and found your hot-spots, it's not a bad thing to have in your back pocket.

Answer (score 4):

In this context it makes little difference, as it already tested for null. Usually you do it this way to make sure you don't call a member on a null-reference (resulting in a NullPointerException), i.e.

```
"test".equals(myString)
```

will never throw a null pointer exception whereas

```
myString.equals("test")
```

will if myString is null. So basically, the first test makes sure it's a string (not null) AND it's equal to "test".

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for using `"constant string".equals(variable)` is that this works properly even if `variable` is `null` (unlike `variable.equals("constant string")`). In your case, however, since you are testing that `string != null` in a short-circuit boolean test, it's entirely a matter of style (or habit).

Answer (score 0):

If they just did this:

```
!"".equals(string);
```

then they're avoiding the possibility of a NullPointerException, which is pretty smart.  However, they're checking for null right before this condition, which is technically not necessary.

Comment: !"".equals(string) gives a different result for when string is null than OPs method.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe Really? I didn't know that. What does it do?

Comment: null != null && !"".equals(null) also returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Is it running any tools like checkstyle? if it is, putting the variable first will result in checkstyle failing. Another reason is that if you put the empty string first it will take away the possibility of getting a null exception if the variable is null because the expression will always evaluate to false.  If you had the variable first and the variable was null it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is more than a coder preference. If the purpose of the method was only to check that string is not an empty String (without caring whether its a null) then it makes sense to have the constant first to avoid a `NullPointerException`.
e.g. This method will return the boolean outcome. false in case string is null.

```
public boolean testString(String string){
    return !"".equals(string);
}
```

while this one may throw a runtime exception if string is null

```
public boolean testString(String string){
    return !string.equals("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is unnatural, and harder to read. It triggers a pause for most readers, and may wastefully consume lots of resources on stackoverlow.com.

(Better use `string.isEmtpy()` anyway)

There are no fixed rules tho, sometime this is easier to read

```
if( null != foobar(blahblahblah, blahblahblah, blahblahblah) )
```

than

```
if( foobar(blahblahblah, blahblahblah, blahblahblah) != null )
```

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered on a number of levels:

1. What does the example mean?

   As other answers have explained, `!"".equals(str)` tests if `str` is an non-empty string.  In general, the `<stringLiteral>.equals(str)` idiom is a neat way of testing a string that deals with the null case without an explicit test.  (If `str` is `null` then the expression evaluates to `false`.
2. Is this particular example best practice?

   In general no.  The `!"".equals(str)` part deals with the case where `str` is null, so the preceding null test is redundant.

   However, if `str` was null in the *vast majority of cases*, this usage would possibly be faster.
3. What is a better way to do this from a code-style perspective?

   `return "".equals(str);`

   or

   `return str != null && !str.isEmpty();`

   However, the second approach doesn't work with Java versions prior to 1.6 ... because `isEmpty()` is a recent API extension.
4. What is the optimal way to do this?

   My gut feeling is that `return str != null && !str.isEmpty();` will be fastest.  The `String.isEmpty()` method is implemented as a one-line test, and is small enough that the JIT compiler will inline it.  The `String.equals(Object)` method is a lot more complicated, and too big to be inlined.

Comment: I believe the question is actually pretty clear: Is there any advantage to doing this particular test compared to the more common test of variable.equals("").

Comment: I didn't say the question is unclear.  I said it can be answered on many levels.  But if you are going to downvote it, I won't bother next time.

Comment: None of your "levels" answered my question at all. That is why it is downvoted. You invented four new questions to answer instead.

Answer (score -1):

Miško Hevery (see his videos on youtube) calls this type of overkill "paranoid programming" :-)

Probably in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w

See also here: http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/09/to-assert-or-not-to-assert/

Comment: how is it overkill? it just tests, whether it's not null and not the empty string (that is, it's a non-empty string). Just `!"".equals(string)` wouldn't catch the null. Anyway, this is not an answer, should probably be a comment instead.

Comment: The solution is to start with an empty string and not with a null. Then run tests, and if you have a null ptr exception, you know that you still have work to do.